# NPE while getting a JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I cannot post the whole code because it is from a huge commercial app. The problem I am facing is in this piece of code

```
public User[] getUsersFromJson()
{
    User[] userArray;
    try
    {
        JSONArray userArrayJson;
        JSONObject jo = GeneralPlugin.settingsData;
        userArrayJson = jo.getJSONArray("PEOPLE");
        userArray= new User[userArrayJson.length()];

        //TEST LOOP; REMOVE ASAP
        for(int i = 0; i < userArrayJson.length(); i++)
        {
            String msg = userArrayJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
            Toast.makeText(ConvoMain.context, "Settings icon " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < userArrayJson.length(); i++)
        {
            userArray[i].setId(userArrayJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            userArray[i].setName(userArrayJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("itemText"));
            userArray[i].setImg(userArrayJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("leftImage"));
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "GET_USERS_FROM_JSON: JSON EXCEPTION CAUGHT IN SETTINGS DATA");
        return null;
    }

    return userArray;
}
```

There is a null pointer exception in this line.

> ```
>         userArrayJson = jo.getJSONArray("PEOPLE");
> ```

**GeneralPlugin.settingsData** is a static **JSONObject** from another public class. From the **toast** I can see that there are *ID*s in the String *msg* so I dont know what is **null**.
Here is the stackTrace

```
10-02 15:10:45.086  26026-26026/com.convo E/GeneralPlugin﹕ null, Exception msg: null
10-02 15:10:45.086  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 15:10:45.086  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.convo.android.model.SettingsData.getUsersFromJson(SettingsData.java:39)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.convo.android.ui.adapter.LeftNavDrawerListAdapter.updateListsAfterLogin(LeftNavDrawerListAdapter.java:85)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.convo.android.ConvoMain$11.run(ConvoMain.java:2715)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4713)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.convo.android.ConvoMain.changeLoginState(ConvoMain.java:2633)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.convo.android.ConvoMain.changeLogin(ConvoMain.java:2934)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.scrybe.plugin.GeneralPlugin$9.run(GeneralPlugin.java:597)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
10-02 15:10:45.096  26026-26026/com.convo W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this might be helpful that I had this code previously working when it was in another class. I messed up when I tried to structure the code and made a new class to handle the **JSON** conversions.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're getting a NPE on that line, it means that `JSONObject jo = GeneralPlugin.settingsData;` does not return a value.

Here's what I would do:

1. Check to make sure that `GeneralPlugin.settingsData` is really returning a value
2. Make sure that `GeneralPlugin.settingsData` is really returning a **JSON** value and not just a value that *LOOKS* like a JSON object.

Comment: Than how come the String *msg* is being correctly populated by the IDs?

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you suggesting that your "TEST LOOP" is executing even though you're getting a NPE at a line prior to that "TEST LOOP" ?

Comment: Yes.And the values are also correct. I compared them manually with the json I am receiving.

Comment: There's something wrong there then. If you're getting an NPE at that line, your code should immediately stop and you shouldn't even get to that "TEST LOOP". Can you check that is really the line where the error is? Also, what do you mean manually compare? A lot of times when people get these sort of errors, it's because they THINK it's a JSON object, when in reality, it's an object that's formatted to LOOK like a JSON object.

Comment: Actually, that makes more sense, given that your "TEST LOOP" is being executed. Check to see **(1)** the length of userArray; make sure the length != 0. **(2)** `userArrayJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")` is returning a value.